# How to populate angular-bootstrap-nav-tree from Api

Tags: angularjs, treeview, asp.net-web-api2

I seem to be missing something here:

I'm trying to use https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree, however it's not loading.

Treeview:

```
<abn-tree tree-data="userPermissions" icon-leaf="material-icons https">
</abn-tree>
```

How I'm trying to load it:

```
$scope.userPermissions = [];

userService.GetUserPermissions(userLoginId).then(function(response) {
        $scope.userPermissions = response.data;
},
function(error) {
    $scope.errors = "Oops! Something went wrong... " + error.statusText;
});
```

I get a No data defined for tree error with this and also with a promise approach:

```
$scope.userPermissions = userService.GetUserPermissions(userLoginId);
```

Does anybody have a working example of how to use this control with non-static data? Is there a better treeview control I can use to display 5 deep nested JSON from an api?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your template is binding to `user.userPermissions` but your controller is setting the data to `$scope.userPermissions`. Change your template binding to `userPermissions` or change your controller to create a `$scope.user` object and set its `userPermissions` property.

Comment: Updated my answer, however that did not seem to fix it.  Seems like a scope binding issue, the directive loads up but the data binds before the call is made.

Comment: I'd take a look at what is coming back in your `response.data`. Maybe it isn't what you think?

Comment: Actually, taking a look into the module you're using it doesn't properly implement attribute binding. It only builds the tree once and doesn't watch for changes on tree data.

I'd look for a different tree view.

Comment: Gotcha, in the trash bin it goes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've used https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control and it works pretty well. Or if you want lots of features and don't mind jQuery, there's an angular wrapper for the popular JSTree. https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree